# Ruby on Rails -- Heroku: Issue with votes button only in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, partial-views, glyphicons

I have an issue with my app's voting button but the issue is only in production. The votes button works in development (locally) but when i deployed the app, the vote button remains un-respensive. When clicked on, it does nothing and there are no messages or indications in the heroku server logs. Infact nothing in the server logs shows anything was clicked. I have looked at my "_vote.html.erb" partial code and i see nothing amiss in it. I however suspect that the issue may be comming from glyphicon bootstrap component i implemented in the partial. I have tried changing the code around to no avail. Still the same issue.  This is the content of the "votes/vote.html.erb" partial:

```
<% if bookmark.votes.find_by(user: current_user).nil? %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" aria-label="Left Align">
    <%= link_to "Like-bookmark", topic_bookmark_votes_path(topic, bookmark), method: :post, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star"%> 
  </button>
<% else %>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" aria-label="Left Align">
    <%= link_to "Unlike-bookmark", topic_bookmark_vote_path(topic, bookmark, bookmark.votes.find_by(user: current_user)), method: :delete, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" %>
  </button>
<% end %>
```

The "_vote.html.erb" partial is being called from the "_bookmark.html.erb" partial so it can render a voting functionality for each bookmark. This is the content of the "bookmarks/bookmark.html.erb" partial

`

```
<% if defined?(upvoted_bookmark) && current_user.bookmarks.include?(upvoted_bookmark) %>

  <div class="panel panel-danger">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="caption">
        <h5>Created by <%= upvoted_bookmark.topic.user.name || upvoted_bookmark.topic.user.email %> on <%= upvoted_bookmark.created_at %></h5> 
        <br>
      </div>
      <div id="bkmak_url">
        <%= link_to upvoted_bookmark.url, topic_bookmark_path(upvoted_bookmark.topic, upvoted_bookmark) %>
      </div>


      <% if policy(Vote.new).create? %>

        <%= render partial: "votes/vote", locals: {topic: upvoted_bookmark.topic, bookmark: upvoted_bookmark} %>
        <br>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>


<% else %>

  <div class="caption">
    <h5>Created by <%= bookmark.topic.user.name || bookmark.topic.user.email %> on <%= bookmark.created_at %></h5> <br>
  </div>

  <div id="bkmak_url" class="btn btn-default btn-xs active">

    <%= link_to bookmark.url, topic_bookmark_path(bookmark.topic, bookmark) %>
  </div>

  <% if policy(bookmark).destroy? %>

    <div class="btn btn-primary btn-md active btn-block">
      <%= link_to "delete bookmark", topic_bookmark_path(bookmark.topic, bookmark), method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this bookmark?" } %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`Like i said before, the issue is only in production. It works perfectly in development (locally). I ran`heroku run rake db:migrate` to make sure my production database schema was properly set up. I run sqlite3 in development and progresql in production (i am aware this is not always advisable). If you need any further code, please let me know and thanking you in advance for your kind and thoughtful help.

Update: ================================================================

@Siguza, thanks. No, I do not have any JS errors in the server logs or console. What worked for me eventually however is to change around the glyphicon component implementation around like so 
  `<% if bookmark.votes.find_by(user: current_user).nil? %>
    <div class="btn btn-info">
    <%= link_to "Like-bookmark", topic_bookmark_votes_path(topic, bookmark), method: :post, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star" %>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="btn btn-warning">
    <%= link_to "Unlike-bookmark", topic_bookmark_vote_path(topic, bookmark, bookmark.votes.find_by(user: current_user)), method: :delete, class: "glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>`
 That got the vote buttons working properly in production.

Comment: Are there any JS errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 2):

It could be an issue with the asset precompiling. I recommend you see the precompiling guidelines for heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-4-asset-pipeline.

Conclusively, enable serve static assets

```
# config/application.rb
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

Add `rails_12factor` gem

```
# Gemfile
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
```

Then precompile your assets

```
$ rake assets:precompile
```

Commit the changes including your `public/assets` folder and push it to heroku.

Comment: Thanks for your hint @Ojash. I tried your reccomendation. I think the system indicated that the command `config.serve_static_assets = true` has been changed to `config.serve_static_files = true`. I tried both anyway (sucessively) but no joy. Still troubleshooting more though. Any more hints are welcome. Inmense thanks again.